# How can I merge pixel data from 800 images with PIL

Tags: python, arrays, python-imaging-library

I'm looping through about 800 images and extracting pixel data in preparation for merging them into 1 image.

At the moment, I extract `r,g,b` values like so:

```
img = Image.open(i, 'r')
data = img.getdata()
rgb_data = []

for (r, g, b) in data:
    rgb_data.append((r, g, b))
```

Getting the rgb values for 1 image is fine. But when attempting to build up a value list of all 800 images rgb values, I run out of memory around image 170. This is because each image contains around 175,000 pixels. So each list has 175,000 values and I'm trying to merge them all together (175,000 * 800).

I've looked into pickling each of the images rgb to a file, then when I have 800 files, loading them all into one list but I run into the same problem.

I've also tried SqlLite, which does work but will probably take days to run. Clocked 1 images rgb values in about 3 hours.

So I'm looking for a way to merge these huge lists into one and somehow not  hold them in memory as much.

EDIT:
To explain further, at the moment theoretically I'll end up with 800 lists, each list containing around 175,000 values for rgb. What I finally want is 1 list of all these values, then I aim to create a new image like so:

```
new_img = Image.new("RGB", size)
new_img.putdata(huge_list_of_all_values)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "merging" will you just add all rgb values to three single values?

Comment: A 3-tuple of integers consumes 156 bytes of memory on my Python 3 installation (`sys.getsizeof(triple) + sum(sys.getsizeof(e) for e in triple)`), so for 800 * 175,000 values like this, you're looking at about 22 gigabytes of memory required plus change for the `rgb_data` list. What are you _actually_ trying to do? How will you merge these values?

Comment: Are you going to average (or use some other filter) the colors and see what you end up with? That's what I get from "merging".

Comment: If you really just want the values read into memory though for merging, you might want to preallocate an `array.array()` to write into; they're cheap for homogenous byte/integer values.

Comment: Thanks @AKX, hadn't considered this, I'll check that out

Comment: @Kevinhowbrook What do you expect the size of that new image to be?

Comment: @AKX No idea... that's probably going to be another thing to work out. The source images are around 340 x 480 at the moment. So massive and probably too big!

Comment: @Kevinhowbrook What exactly are you trying to do? What does "merge" mean? Are you trying to tile the images and create a grid? Try to be more specific. Your actual problem might not be what you think it is. See [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @akinuri, thanks. By merge I essentially mean combine values from 800 lists into 1 list. So I end up with 1 object/list with all the data from each image.

Comment: @Kevinhowbrook Yes, but what would you do with the data? I don't believe that you'll just be "There, sorted! :-)" and go do something else once you do have the list of values... :)